# Fastest way to move image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, correlation

I develop a simple stabilizer and I'm having difficulty with the shift of the image. Example - I have two images (A and B) are shifted relative to each other by a few pixels. I calculate the offset using phase correlations. The next step I need to move the second image by the image's offset. An example is presented on the image. How do I solve this problem?

There is link to preview image:

[image: illustration]

Comment: can you show any code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: If you can embed your images in bigger images from the beginning (and if you can limit the shift by maximum size of the border) you can use subimages instead of moving anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cv::Rect and cv::Mat::copyTo

```
cv::Mat img=cv::imread("image.jpg");
cv::Mat imgTranslated(img.size(),img.type(),cv::Scalar::all(0));
img(cv::Rect(50,30,img.cols-50,img.rows-30)).copyTo(imgTranslated(cv::Rect(0,0,img.cols-50,img.rows-30)));
```

Answer (score 2):

setTo(0) the destination image, then use the operator() of cv::Mat to create a subimage of the input image and of the output image (you'll use 2 cv::Rect with same size and different displacement; the size is dependent on the displacement, i.e. bigger displacement means smaller part of the image you can copy in output). Then use method copyTo.

Said this: normally when asking a question you would show some code showing what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

My implementation allows the shift to be in *any* direction...

```
using namespace cv;
//and whatever header 'abs' requires...

Mat offsetImageWithPadding(Const Mat& originalImage, int offsetX, int offsetY, Scalar backgroundColour){
        padded = Mat(originalImage.rows + 2 * abs(offsetY), originalImage.cols + 2 * abs(offsetX), CV_8UC3, backgroundColour);
        originalImage.copyTo(padded(Rect(abs(offsetX), abs(offsetY), originalImage.cols, originalImage.rows)));
        return Mat(padded,Rect(abs(offsetX) + offsetX, abs(offsetY) + offsetY, originalImage.cols, originalImage.rows));
}

//example use with black borders along the right hand side and top:
Mat offsetImage = offsetImageWithPadding(originalImage, -10, 6, Scalar(0,0,0));
```

It's taken from my own working code but some variables changed, if it doesn't compile, very likely just a small thing needs changing - but you get the idea re. the abs function...